# three.js black/White screen before moving mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I decided to use a 3D WebGL viewer to put on my website, but i have a small issue.

Everything work fine, I can move my object and see it, but when I load the page, the screen is black before I move the mouse while clicking.
So it's not an issue for me, but for people visiting my website : they can't guess they should move my object, and enjoy the viewer, and they could think it's a bug.

here is my webpage :

http://urlz.fr/1SQj

I thought about a solution, but I'm not able (not yet !!) to do this :

- when the script is load, just rotate the object until the user click on the item (I think, as the object is moving, the black screen will disapear immediatly, because it does when I move the mouse).

What do you think about ?

Thank you very much,

ngt78

Comment: Just call `render()` after object is loaded. Works for me.

Comment: Martin is correct. You are only calling render() with `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );` and in your resize listener. Are you sure you don't want to be calling render in your animate function (notice how stats is not updating)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies.
I updated my code on my local website, and I add render() after object is loaded, but the object still don't appear. The screen is white instead of being black but we can't see the object before mouse-moving it

Comment: Actually, you have a couple of different options. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only calling the render function from the controls listener and the window resize listener.

If you only want to render when the controls are changed, you could remove the animate function altogether and call `render` instead of `animate` at the start of your script.

If you want to render every frame, call your render function from your animate function. You could probably get rid of the controls listener then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Your first solution made my screen white, without the object.
Your second worked fine, but now every frame is rendered (I call render into animate), so it appears immediatly but i'm in trouble with fps :/
EDIT : sorry, it finally works! in fact, I just had to wait until it's loaded, I think ! but no trouble until 5 seconds waiting :)
Thank you very much !!

Comment: Oh yes, with the first option you would also want to call the render function  in the loader callback function.